# Using Pi as a router doesn't Internet - funky iptables?

Tags: wifi, iptables

I'm using this [Adafruit guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software) for turning my Raspberry Pi 2 B+ into a wifi router. I've got all the software installed and it works! Well, sort of.

I can connect to the router A-OK, and if I run

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then I can navigate to `172.16.1.1:8000` and I get the webpage just fine. So I know traffic is working to/from the pi. However, I can't get beyond that. `ping 8.8.8.8` doesn't work with:

```
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

Trying to ping an actual domain name (e.g. `mit.edu` or `google.com`) fails with

```
ping: cannot resolve mit.edu: unknown host
```

My only thought is that it's iptables not working correctly, but it looks just like the screenshot from the Adafruit guide:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

And I know that I can get to the Internet from my Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Other relevant sections:

**/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
 address 172.16.1.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**:

```
# Don't worry about eth0's network
subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
}

subnet 172.16.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 172.16.1.100 172.16.1.200;
 option broadcast-address 172.16.1.255;
 option routers 172.16.1.1;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;
 option domain-name "local";
 option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

**/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**:

DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
INTERFACES=""

**/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**:

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=my_network
channel=1
#bridge=br0

# WPA and WPA2 configuration

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=surewhynotputmyrealpasswordhere
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# Hardware configuration

driver=nl80211
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
device_name=RTL8192CU
manufacturer=Realtek
```

**/etc/default/hostapd**:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etct/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

**netstat -au** (on the raspberry pi):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ netstat -au
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
udp        0      0 *:52375                 *:*
udp        0      0 *:43975                 *:*
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*
udp        0      0 *:bootps                *:*
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*
udp        0      0 raspberrypi.local:ntp   *:*
udp        0      0 172.16.1.1:ntp          *:*
udp        0      0 192.168.42.134:ntp      *:*
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:42265              [::]:*
udp6       0      0 fe80::6cce:ea5d:5d7:ntp [::]:*
udp6       0      0 fe80::ee35:b0ca:cdc:ntp [::]:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:52608              [::]:*
```

**More updates**:

So, the strangeness - it seems that I can connect just fine via my Samsung Galaxy Note Tablet and my alcatel cell phone. <strike>I haven't tried chromebooks  yet, but</strike> it *appears* that just my Mac is having the trouble connecting.

(tried with chromebooks now, it works just fine)

Comment: What is your question in detail? i.e. How it is not working. what you have tried.
Check whether port 80 is opened. cmd: netstat -au

Comment: You have described what works, but I fail to see any information about what doesn't work. What have you tried, and how does it fail?

Comment: Whoops, my bad - I was worried about getting the information on what my settings were that I forgot to include that. Included now :) (I can't get to the internet from a device connected via wifi)

Comment: @Sean83 added netstat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it [wasn't IP tables at all](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/261987/132617).

> It looks like something was horked up with my routing table. [Flushing
>   my
>   routes](https://serverfault.com/questions/78365/how-to-reload-default-mac-osx-routing-table-without-rebooting)
>   with
>
> ```
> $ sudo route -n flush
> ```
>
> at the terminal several times, clearing my custom DNS entries, and
>   turning my wifi off and then on again allows me to connect properly.

I discovered this because I added another DNS entry that showed up when I was connected to my old router and was able to connect. Then I used the [Mac network utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Utility) to traceroute to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, but they both failed with `traceroute: bind: Can't assign requested address`. That lead me to [flushing the routes](https://serverfault.com/a/80446/46824), which solved my problem.